# Initialize struct varargs

Tags: c, struct, variadic-functions

I want to fill an entire struct in varargs. I know all single elements of the struct can be filled with `int16_t *x = va_arg(args, int16_t*);` But I am looking for a more efficient way so that I can make use of `memset`. I tried to use the same code for the whole struct as shown below. But this does not work. So is there a way to initialize the whole struct with only one `va_args` argument, instead of varargs for all single elements.

```
typedef struct {
    int16_t x;          
    int16_t y;      
} Coordinate;

void AddValues(int count, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);

    Coordinate *dec = va_arg(args, Coordinate*);
    *dec.x = 10;
    *dec.y = 5;
    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    Coordinate cor;
    AddValues(2, &cor);
    printf("x: %d and y: %d\n", cor.x, cor.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`va_arg(args, Coordinate)` should be `va_arg(args, Coordinate *)`.

You can assign the whole structure with a *compound literal*:

```
*va_arg(args, Coordinate *) = (Coordinate) { 10, 5 };
```

`void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly legal to use a struct type with the `va_arg` macro. The requirement is that

> The parameter type shall be a *type* name specified such that the type
>   of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained
>   simply by postfixing a `*` to *type*.

The result of an invocation of `va_arg` is of that type, *not* a pointer to the type. You're assigning a value of type `Coordinate` to `dec`, which is of type `Coordinate*`. Fix that, and adjust the rest of the code accordingly, and you should be able to make it work.

Also:

`void main()` is incorrect. Use `int main(void)`.

The code in your question is missing at least three required `#include` directives.

Your code defines `AddValues` but calls `AddValuesOriginal`.

If you tell us "But this does not work.", you need to show us exactly *how* it doesn't work. Include any error messages in your question, formatted as code.